# jquery validate work for first input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

In my View. Each field  has validation. Here is some sample code...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home"))
{
<button>отправить</button>
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Number,new {Id=i,Name=i})

}
}
```

My model

```
   public class Class1
{
    [Required]
    public decimal Number { get; set; }
}
```

Jquery validate work for first input.have any ideas?

Comment: Can you try with  @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Number,new { @id=i, @name=i}) to check what happens?

Comment: validattion not wort f on the same page more than one  @Html.TextBoxFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Class1
{
    [Required]
    public decimal Number { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class1[] items { get; set; }
}
```

View code:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Class2
```

...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.items[i].Number, new { Id = i, Name = i })

}
```